# Alternative of ST_DWithin of PostGIS in python shapely

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, shapely

I've two linestrings Line1,Line2.

```
line1 = "LINESTRING(72.863221 18.782499,72.863736 18.770147,72.882275 18.756169,72.881417 18.750805,72.878842 18.736987,72.874379 18.709512,72.860989 18.679593,72.864422 18.653897)"
line2 = "LINESTRING(72.883133 18.780793,72.882103 18.760314,72.862534 18.716422,72.860474 18.683577)"
```

I'm trying to perform the following query of POSTGIS in shapely. As of now I haven't been able to find the alternative of ST_DWithin command.

```
road2 = "ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;%s')"%line1
road4 = "ST_GeographyFromText('SRID=4326;%s')"%line2
cur.execute("SELECT ST_AsText(road1) from %s as road1,%s as road2 
            where ST_DWithin(road1,road2,500)"%(road2,road4))
res = cur.fetchall()
print res
```

Does anyone knows what is the alternative of ST_DWithin in shapely ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, shapely only supports operations in planar coordinates (no geography types). However, for LineStrings which are not too large so that the curvature of the globe can be neglected, one could partially "circumvent" this by:

- working in some planar projection (for example directly in the lat/lon or lon/lat coordinates)
- following the second note in the documentation of [`ST_DWithin`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) and the first note in the documentation of [`ST_Expand`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Expand.html), i.e.:

  1. checking if the bounding box of the second LineString intersects with the expanded bounding box of the first LineString
  2. if yes, checking if the minimum distance is indeed below the prescribed threshold

For example:

```
from shapely.wkt import dumps, loads
from shapely.geometry.geo import box

spec = [
    "LINESTRING(72.863221 18.782499,72.863736 18.770147,72.882275 18.756169,72.881417 18.750805,72.878842 18.736987,72.874379 18.709512,72.860989 18.679593,72.864422 18.653897)",
    "LINESTRING(72.883133 18.780793,72.882103 18.760314,72.862534 18.716422,72.860474 18.683577)"
]

lines = list(map(loads, spec))

eta = 0.005

b1 = box(*lines[0].bounds).buffer(eta)
b2 = box(*lines[1].bounds)

flag = b2.intersects(b1) and (lines[0].distance(lines[1]) < eta)
print(eta, flag)
```

Alternatively, if you would like to check if the entire second LineString is within prescribed threshold from the first LineString, you could also use the `buffer` method as:

```
lines[0].buffer(eta).contains(lines[1])
```

The threshold supplied here to the `buffer` method is expressed in the same coordinate system in which the LineStrings are defined. Within the lon/lat system, this would represent the "central angle" - the issue then consists in the fact that the [great circle distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) corresponding to a fixed `eta` not only depends on the particular values of latitude and longitude but also on the direction of the displacement. However, if the LineStrings are not too large and the required precision is not too high, it probably won't [matter that much](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/algorithm-for-offsetting-a-latitude-longitude-by-some-amount-of-meters).